# How to move the cursor sequentially?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

The problem can be divided into 2 smaller ones:

1. ReleaseMouseButton(3) is called before the corresponding bullet is fired in the game (thus now I have coded 30 bullets, and it completes execution in the first two or three). I decided to increase the delay through Sleep(50), this gave the expected effect, albeit a weak one, but this is also not an option. there is a much shorter time interval between bullets.
2. Each mouse shift works in such a way that the previous one breaks. For example, let's call:

```
MoveMouseRelative(0, 0)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 15)
Sleep(10)
MoveMouseRelative(0, 5)
```

For some reason, the third affects the second, and the second affects the first, so I have to adjust all the offsets when adding a new one, and this is a very boring thing and definitely should not work like that.

Functions like EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents can be viewed in pdf logitech g-series lua api https://douile.com/logitech-toggle-keys/APIDocs.pdf

Whole code:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
     EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
       repeat
          MoveMouseRelative(0.15)
          Sleep(50)
          MoveMouseRelative(0,40)
          Sleep(50)
          MoveMouseRelative(0,30)
          Sleep(90)
          --MoveMouseRelative(0.9)
          Sleep(100)
          --MoveMouseRelative(0.7) -- 5
          Sleep(10)
         
          if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
         
          --[[MoveMouseRelative(0,6)
          Sleep(10)
           MoveMouseRelative(0.6)
          Sleep(10)
          MoveMouseRelative(0.6)
          Sleep(10)
          MoveMouseRelative(0.6)
          Sleep(10)
          MoveMouseRelative(0,6) -- 10
          Sleep(10)
         
          if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
         
          MoveMouseRelative(0.6)
          Sleep(10)
           MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(10)
           MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
           MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
           MoveMouseRelative(0,7) -- 15
          Sleep(15)
         
          if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
         
           MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
          MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
          MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
          MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
          MoveMouseRelative(0,7) -- 20
          Sleep(15)
         
          if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
         
           MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
           MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
           MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
           MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
           MoveMouseRelative(0,7) -- 25
          Sleep(15)
         
          if not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then break end
         
          MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
          MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
          MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
          MoveMouseRelative(0.7)
          Sleep(15)
          MoveMouseRelative(0,7) -- 30
          Sleep(15)]]--
         
          ReleaseMouseButton(3)
         
          --OutputLogMessage("Repeat")
       until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) -- btn#4 is bound to btn#10
       --OutputLogMessage("Stop")
    end
end
```

Comment: `For some reason, the third affects the second, and the second affects the first` can you elaborate on that? What absolute x mouse coord to you expect when you call let's say `MoveMouseRelative(10, 0); MoveMouseRelative(15, 0)`, assuming you start from 0, 0?

Comment: @Luke100000 i'm wait move first to x +10 y + 0, second to x + 15, y + 0, but idk how this works, if i try this, my frist maybe x=10+15, and second too or idk, this script for g hub, u can try for more information

Comment: Your guess is correct, and everything else would contradict the name of the function. Thus I'm still not sure what your question exactly is. If you need a "MouseMoveRelativeToOrigin" you need to make a custom function which keeps track of the current offset.

Comment: @Luke100000 I don’t even understand the difference between relative offset and absolute, I just want in the game, when I run the macro, each offset works as a separate entity, does not affect the previous offset, but takes it into account, perhaps or I don’t know how to describe it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function mentioned by Luke in comments might look like the following:

```
local last_x, last_y

function SetOrigin()
   last_x, last_y = 0, 0
end

function SmoothMouseMoveRelativeToOrigin(x, y, ms)
   last_x, last_y, x, y = x, y, x - last_x, y - last_y
   local tm = GetRunningTime()
   local prev_dx, prev_dy = 0, 0
   repeat
      Sleep(10)
      local t = GetRunningTime() - tm
      local dt = math.min(ms, t) / ms
      local dx = math.floor(dt * x + 0.5)
      local dy = math.floor(dt * y + 0.5)
      prev_dx, prev_dy, dx, dy = dx, dy, dx - prev_dx, dy - prev_dy
      if dx ~= 0 or dy ~= 0 then
         MouseMoveRelative(dx, dy)
      end
   until t >= ms
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   SetOrigin()
   ....
      repeat
         SmoothMouseMoveRelativeToOrigin(0, 15, 50)  -- after 50 ms: at (0, 15)
         SmoothMouseMoveRelativeToOrigin(0, 20, 40)  -- after 50+40 ms: at (0, 20), not (0, 35)
   ....
end
```

Comment: thx u very much, i try it later and send feed back

Comment: this works, but in game very much twitches, its not cool, thx u! I select this like answer, can u help me with fix twitches?

Comment: i try it now, thx u, i can't set delay more than 10ms because bullets have 5-15 delay

Comment: Smooth movement may have arbitrary duration (ms)

Comment: `bullets have 5-15 delay` - what do you mean?

Comment: yep, i speak, but idk what i need for make this macros, my first exp, now he work not good, maybe i'm bad use your example? We can call in discord? Of course if u have time and desire/wish idk how translate this

Comment: On one website i read what if set delay 0 for controlling mouse, can get ban from anti-cheat and between shots have delay, idk how much, but he have delay, i try near ~10ms

Comment: I don't have Discord.  Welcome to the [SO chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253399/logitech-gaming-software).  I added 10 reputation points to you so that you can enter the chat (20 rep is required)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253400/discussion-between-john-house-and-eskri).